# Rundeck: SSH User from Docker Container to Host?

Tags: docker, rundeck

I am trying to get rundeck up using docker (jordan/rundeck:latest)

Everything seems to work ok except that I can seem to SSH to the host as the user I want.

Here is the docker run command I am running:

```
sudo docker run -p 4443:4443 
-e EXTERNAL_SERVER_URL=https://domain:4443 
-e RUNDECK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password 
-e RUNDECK_PASSWORD=password 
-e RUNDECK_WITH_SSL=true --name rundeck3 
--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway -t 
jordan/rundeck:latest
```

I created a new password in key storage, a new project with OpenSSH as the node executor, and created a new node with the correct info. But when I run a simple `whoami` command on the node I get `rundeck`

I can `ssh user@host.docker.internal` with the same credentials through `docker exec` so I don't think it's a connectivity issue.

[image: rundeck screenshot]

Am I missing something? Going crazy here…

Comment: ssh command and actual output?

Comment: @RickRackow other than what I shared?It is in the screenshot as well, although slightly hidden. But I ran ‘whoami’ and got back ‘rundeck’

Comment: Hi! Could you share your node definitions (Project Settings > Edit nodes) and the remote ssh node definition (maybe a resources.xml file?).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Rundeck/comments/134zmd0/so_confused/). Remove the localhost entry in your yaml node definition. You can manage the local node using the specific local model source entry and the remote nodes on the yaml/xml node definition file.